# Screen Rotation not working in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, display-rotation

I have an HP x360 2in1 notebook, recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3

I noticed the screen rotation icon at the top right menu but automatic screen rotation is not working.

I come from Ubuntu Unity 16.04 where this never worked for me, and this is not a feature I value too much.. but seeing the lock-rotation button on the menu made me wonder why it doesn't work.

I have seen some threads on disabling the screen rotation, but none on enabling it. Is there a way to make it work? I cannot find any settings or configurations.