# Screen rotation died

Tags: display-rotation

Similar to the unanswered: [Screen Rotation not working in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949538/screen-rotation-not-working-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04)

- Device: Lenovo Yoga 910
- Ubuntu version: 17.10

My auto-rotation just up and stopped working on me.  Was working fine and then I did a couple `apt-get upgrade` and installed some bits of software I was experimenting with and now it just doesn't function.

There's the icon in the drop-down as mentioned in the above question.  It's not locked.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock
false
```

And that's about as far as I could get with my google-fu.  I see no indication it should not work.  Any indicator I can find says it should be on.  Is there perhaps a module I need that might not be loading anymore?

I'm afraid my Linux Guru status has long since passed; since switching to Ubuntu I just don't generally have to mess with crap.  I'm ready to just do a re-install but first asking here.

Again, was working just fine a few days ago when last I wanted to flip my lid and read something.

Oh, and I'm pretty damn sure nothing I newly installed messed anything up.  My guess is I must have hosed some setting I cannot find, or some upgrade occurred that broke it.  Stuff I've been installing has to do with microservices and docker and crap.

Comment: I just wiped everything and re-installed and it works now.